# Micronaut: is it possible to write value to application.yml?

Tags: java, properties, yaml, micronaut

i have a micronaut application with application.yml like this

```yaml
key:
 value: foo
```

is there any way i can store some value in key.value property ?
So eventually i want something like this:

```java
public void store(String value) {
  SomeKindOfMicronautYamlAppPropertiesHolder appProps = new SomeKindOfMicronautYamlAppPropertiesHolder();
  appProps.getProperty("key.value").write(value);
}
```

i'm wondering if it can be done using only micronaut

Comment: I would like to know the use case here. Why do you want to edit the application.yml file at run-time?

Comment: If you are talking about the application updating the contents of its own `.jar` file and having that affect the running instance, there really is no good reason to do that.  Is your real requirement just that you need to dynamically update config values in the running app (without manipulating the contents of the `.jar` file)?